# What is a suitable word for a desired/ideal level of education?

Tags: word-choice

Boss speaking to employee:

> "yes, you have the minimum education level but I'd say that for this task the __________ education level is X"

I used the word "minimum", but is there a better way of saying it?

(I need to say that for doing a specific task (such as "calling a customer on the phone") there is a minimum level of education.)

Saying "ideal education" is not good because it can mean "the highest possible education".

Should I say "desired education"?

Comment: Could it be "Optimal", according to http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/41079/optimal-vs-ideal?rq=1 ???

Comment: Downvotes with no comment are useless, I am italian so I don't speak perfect english, I guess i made many mistakes in my question, is this a good reason to downvote? (in stackoverflow.com where i am an active member there is the hidden rule of always commenting when downvoting, if not it is like throwing stones at random: no use)

Comment: Perhaps "the *preferred* education level is..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using:

> [**required**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/require)

e.g. 
"For this task the ***required*** education level is a college degree."

Comment: +1_Required_ is a good choice because it's more specific than "minimum" and not ambiguous like "preferred" (which implies that even if you don't have the minimum or preferred level of education, I might hire you if you're pretty enough or if you put out).

Comment: Required makes me think of minimum too, or not? Anyway I trust Bill Franke!

Comment: If a particular level of education is what you require, then surely you should call it "required".

Answer (score 5):

If you have a specific educational standard that all applicants must meet, it's called a "prerequisite."

> prerequisite (adj):
>   1.
>   required beforehand

*The prerequisite education for this job is a High School diploma.*

A google books search shows that this expression is commonly used in expressing the specific requirements for employees. Such as this [passage](http://books.google.es/books?id=CMZCn8MYV40C&pg=PA24&dq=%22prerequisite%20education%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=OY7AUM7RD5KRhQeP2ICgDA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22prerequisite%20education%22&f=false)...

> The training process cannot proceed effectively unless learners have the prerequisite education.

Or [this](http://books.google.es/books?id=Tz0rAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA116&dq=%22prerequisite%20education%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=OY7AUM7RD5KRhQeP2ICgDA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22prerequisite%20education%22&f=false)...

> Mandatory prerequisite education and training would provide consistency of knowledge among vessel operators.

To be clear, a prerequisite is a requirement for a specific educational standard which is not necessarily synonymous with a minimum standard. So, a minimum standard would be a High School education with a *prerequisite educational requirement* of fluency in Spanish.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using "desired".

> Although you meet the minimum level of education, the **desired** level of education for this job is YYYY.

or maybe "preferred".

> Although you meet the minimum level of education, the **preferred** level of education for this job is YYYY.

Answer (score 0):

As the others have mentioned, you can use "prerequisite" or "required".

But another way is to use additional words to disambiguate the meaning of the ambiguous words used:

> "Yes, you have the minimum education level **by law**, but I'd say that the minimum education level for this task is X."